# knapsack with requirement to select one item each from many sets

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I have an understanding of the basic [0-1 knapsack problem](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/0-1) and its solution. I am trying to reason through a variant of the 0-1 problem where instead of being able to select any combination of items from a single list, you *must* select exactly one item each from many sets of different items.

For example, in my problem, the item list would look like:

#### Food

- Banana (weight 9, value 10)
- Bread (weight 3, value 25)
- Apple (weight 4, value 30)
- ...

#### Shirts

- T-shirt (weight 2, value 20)
- Button-down shirt (weight 3, value 25)
- ...

#### Pants

- Khakis (weight 4, value 30)
- Jeans (weight 2, value 30)
- ...

and so on, where the problem *requires* that you select exactly one item from Food, one item from Shirts, one item from Pants, and so on.

I *think* have a brute force solution that I modified from Rosetta Code and seems to work (below) but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a more efficient dynamic programming solution. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction? I'd appreciate it.

```
from itertools import product

def anycomb(item1, item2, item3, item4):
    return ( comb
             for comb in product(item1, item2, item3, item4)
             )

def totalvalue(comb):
    ' Totalise a particular combination of items'
    totwt = totval = 0
    for item, wt, val in comb:
        totwt  += wt
        totval += val
    return (totval, -totwt) if totwt <= 400 else (0, 0)

itemset_1 = (
    ("map", 9, 150), ("compass", 13, 35), ("water", 153, 200), ("sandwich", 50, 160),
    ("glucose", 15, 60))
itemset_2 = (
    ("tin", 68, 45), ("banana", 27, 60), ("apple", 39, 40),
    ("cheese", 23, 30), ("suntan cream", 11, 70))
itemset_3 = (
    ("beer", 52, 10), ("camera", 32, 30),
    ("t-shirt", 24, 15), ("trousers", 48, 10), ("umbrella", 73, 40),
    ("waterproof trousers", 42, 70))
itemset_4 = (
    ("waterproof overclothes", 43, 75),
    ("note-case", 22, 80), ("sunglasses", 7, 20), ("towel", 18, 12),
    ("socks", 4, 50), ("book", 30, 10))

bagged = max( anycomb(itemset_1, itemset_2, itemset_3, itemset_4), key=totalvalue) # max val or min wt if values equal
print("Bagged the following items\n  " +
      '\n  '.join(sorted(item for item,_,_ in bagged)))
val, wt = totalvalue(bagged)
print("for a total value of %i and a total weight of %i" % (val, -wt))
```

Comment: You can do a 3D DP over here with state as DP( number of items left in the list , number of lists , sum ) . Then whenever you choose the current item just reduce the number of lists!! It has a tag python elsewise I could have given you some c++ code

Comment: what are the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution of [basic 0-1 knapsack](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/0-1#C.2B.2B) problem with a little change.
When you choose to select an item, you must go to the last item of previous set.
It means :

F(i,w) = max[ F(i-1 , w) , F(A[i]-1 , w-w[i]) + P[i] ]

where A[i] means index of the first item of the set which i'th item belongs to.